# Torsion points on twists of elliptic curves and products of fine modular curves over $\mathcal{M}_{1,1}$ vs over the $j$-line

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $Y_1(n)$ (for $n\ge 4$) be the fine moduli scheme over $\mathbb{Q}$ parametrizing elliptic curves with a rational point of order $n$. Let $\mathbb{A}^1_j$ be the $j$-line over $\mathbb{Q}$, the coarse moduli scheme of the moduli stack of elliptic curves $\mathcal{M}_{1,1}$ (over $\mathbb{Q}$). Let $\mathcal{M}_{1,1}^\circ$ be the open substack classifying elliptic curves with $j$-invariant $\notin\{0,1728\}$. Let $Y_1(n)^\circ$ be the open subscheme obtained by removing the fibers above $j = 0,1728$, and let $\mathbb{A}_j^{1\circ}$ be the $j$-line minus $0,1728$.

One may consider the fiber products 
$$A := Y_1(5)^\circ\times_{\mathcal{M}_{1,1}^\circ}Y_1(7)^\circ,\qquad B := Y_1(5)^\circ\times_{\mathbb{A}_j^{1\circ}}Y_1(7)^\circ$$

Both $A,B$ are schemes. $Y_1(7)^\circ$ is finite etale over $\mathcal{M}_{1,1}^\circ$ of degree $[SL_2(\mathbb{Z}):\Gamma_1(7)] = 48$, in the sense that the fiber category above a geometric point $\text{Spec }k\rightarrow\mathcal{M}_{1,1}^\circ$ is a groupoid with 48 objects, but with isomorphisms between them (48 should be the degree according to the definition of the [Galois category of an algebraic stack](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0201021.pdf)). Thus, since we're staying away from $j = 0,1728$, the resulting scheme theoretic fiber should have degree 24 over $\text{Spec }k$. For the same reason, $A$ should be finite etale over $Y_1(5)^\circ$ of degree 24.

Similarly, $Y_1(7)^\circ$ is finite etale over $\mathbb{A}_j^{1\circ}$, and so the pullback $B$ is finite etale over $Y_1(5)^\circ$, also of degree 24.

The universal property of fiber products provides a map $A\rightarrow B$ (commuting with the finite etale maps to $Y_1(5)^\circ$). This map must then also be finite etale, and by comparing degrees, must be an isomorphism.

Is this correct? (That $A\cong B$?)

In particular, this would seem to say that if we have an elliptic curve $E_1/K$ with a point $P_1$ of order 5, and an elliptic curve $E_2/K$ with a point $P_2$ of order 7, such that $j(E_1) = j(E_2) \ne 0,1728$, then this pair $((E_1,P_1),(E_2,P_2))$ would correspond to a $K$-point of $B$, and hence a $K$-point of $A$, but by definition of the fiber product of stacks, giving such a $K$-point of $A$ would imply that in fact $E_1\cong E_2$ over $K$ - which says more than just $j(E_1) = j(E_2)$ - ie, $E_1$ is not a twist of $E_2$.

If so this seems quite striking. In particular, this would seem to imply that if an elliptic curve $E/K$ with automorphism group $\{\text{id},[-1]\}$ has a $K$-point of order $n\ge 4$ (so that $Y_1(n)$ is a fine moduli scheme), then none of the twists of $E/K$ can have $K$-points of order $\ge 4$. Ie, amongst the set of all twists of $E$, at most one can admit a $K$-rational point of order $\ge 4$.

Comment: The ramification does not really cancel: for this to happen one must take the normalisation of the fibre product. (The fibre product will never be smooth in such a situation.)

Comment: Take X and Y to be points and $\mathcal M =BG $ for a dramatic failure of your guess in the last paragraph.

Comment: @ulrich That's a great point actually. However the issue should go away if one avoids elliptic curves of $j$-invariant 0,1728 right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your degree calculation is bogus. You write:

> $Y_1(7)^\circ$ is finite etale over $\mathcal{M}_{1,1}^\circ$ of degree $[SL_2(\mathbb{Z}):\Gamma_1(7)] = 48$, in the sense that the fiber category above a geometric point $\text{Spec }k\rightarrow\mathcal{M}_{1,1}^\circ$ is a groupoid with 48 objects, but with isomorphisms between them  [...] The resulting scheme theoretic fiber should have degree 24 over $\text{Spec }k$.

But the map  $Y_1(7)^\circ \to \mathcal{M}_{1,1}^\circ$  is representable, and this means in particular that the fiber category over $\text{Spec }k$ (or over any scheme for that matter) is an algebraic space, not a stack. So the only isomorphisms in your 48-object category are identities, and the "scheme theoretic fiber" should have degree 48 over $\text{Spec }k$.

Comment: ... and we find that $A$ is finite étale over $Y_1(5)^\circ$ of degree 48, not 24.

Comment: Ahh...okay I see my mistake. I was thinking that the fiber category is fibered in setoids with 48 objects, but 24 isomorphism classes. Now I see where I went wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I can't say for sure whether or not $A \cong B$, but it's *not* true that if $E_{1}/K$ and $E_{2}/K$ are elliptic curves with $j(E_{1}) = j(E_{2}) \not\in \{ 0, 1728 \}$ and $P_{1} \in E_{1}(K)$ and $P_{2} \in E_{2}(K)$ both have order $\geq 4$ then necessarily $E_{1} \cong E_{2}$.

In particular, take $E_{1} : y^{2} + xy = x^{3} - 540x + 777615$. This is the "default" elliptic curve with $j = -1/15$, which forces $E_{1}$ to have a cyclic 4-isogeny defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $E_{2}$ be the quadratic twist of $E_{1}$ by $161$ - then $E_{2}$ has a $\mathbb{Q}$-rational 4-torsion point.

Now, let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be the degree 24 extension obtained by adjoining to $\mathbb{Q}$ the coordinates of a $5$-torsion point of $E_{1}$. Magma tells me that the torsion subgroup of $E_{1}/K$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$. In particular, $E_{1}$ and $E_{2}$ are not isomorphic over $K$, but $j(E_{1}) = j(E_{2}) = -1/15$ and $E_{1}(K)$ and $E_{2}(K)$ both contain torsion points of order $\geq 4$.

Comment: Interesting... in fact according to [lmfdb](http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/), there are two nonisomorphic elliptic curves over Q with j-invariant -1/15 each admitting a point of order 4, so what I said is definitely wrong. Though...I'm still not sure where the flaw in the argument is.